# queryメソッドを使用すると”TypeError: string indices must be integers”とエラーが発生してしまう

Tags: python, python3, google-bigquery

■やりたいこと
big queryのテーブルをqueryメソッドを使い操作したい

■やったこと
こちらのURLのスクリプトをそのまま実行
https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/usage/queries.html

■起きたこと
最初は問題なく動いたが、何故か途中でエラーがでてしまうようになった
エラー内容：TypeError: string indices must be integers

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()

query = """
    SELECT name, SUM(number) as total_people
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_2013`
    WHERE state = 'TX'
    GROUP BY name, state
    ORDER BY total_people DESC
    LIMIT 20
"""
query_job = client.query(query)  # Make an API request.

print("The query data:")
for row in query_job:
    # Row values can be accessed by field name or index.
    print("name={}, count={}".format(row[0], row["total_people"]))
```

最初は上記のコードをそのまま実行し、動作確認をして動いていた気がするのですが
途中でエラーがでてしまいうまくいきません。

どなたかおわかりになる方いましたら、ご教示いただけますと幸いです。

Comment: 質問の内容で調べられるのは現在 Google Cloud にアクセス出来る人だけでしょうね。表示されたエラーメッセージの全文や、エラー発生時の関連する変数などの内容を調べてすべて提示すれば、それで推測できて答えられる人がいるかもしれません。ちなみに`print("name={}, count={}".format(row[0], row["total_people"]))`とか言う風にフォーマットした内容では無く、`print(row)`や`print(row[0])`とか`print(dir(row))`や`print(dir(row[0]))`とかでフォーマットしないで表示することは出来るのでしょうか？ あるいは、仕様が変わったか何かして、`row`が2次元配列で返される場合があるとか？ その場合、`print("name={}, count={}".format(row[0][0], row[0]["total_people"]))`という風にして表示出来るか試してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: 一日おいて試してみたところ、問題なく動作しました。
時間をおいたら動くようになるなどあるのでしょうか、不思議です。

Comment: 一時的な異常だったということですかね。

Comment: そうかもしれません。アドバイスいただきありがとうございました。